# Calculations involving differential forms and determining the meaning of a symbol

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $J=]0,1[ \in \mathbb{R}$,
If $\alpha$ is a $1$-differential form: $\alpha = \left(\dfrac{\log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{\log(1-x)}{y}\right)dy \in \Omega^1(J^2)$.

I am to find $f\in \Omega^0(J^2)$ such that $\rho^{\star}(\alpha) - \alpha = df$

Where $\rho: J^2 \rightarrow J^2$ is defined by $\rho(a,b) = (b,a)$

Now I encounter a problem when trying to compute $\rho^{*}(\alpha)$: It was suggested in the answer to use the following property: $\rho^*(fdy)=(f \circ \rho)d(y \circ \rho)$

Now in my case: $f = \Big(\dfrac{\log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{\log(1-x)}{y}\Big)$

I tried to compute $\rho^{*}(\alpha)$ as I'm having trouble seeing what $(f \circ \rho)$ is.

Comment: Your $\alpha$ looks like a $1$-form to me, it's only get a $dy$ term, a $2$-form would have a wedge product of two (distinct) differentials.

Comment: $\rho^*$ is the pullback with respect to the map $\rho$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\phi: M^m \to N^n$ then given $p \in M^m$ we have the push-forward map $\phi_{*,p}: T_pM^m \to T_{\phi(p)}N^n$. We get the pull-back map denoted $(\phi_{*,p})^*:= \phi^*: T_{\phi(p)}^* N^n \to T_p^*M^m$ given by:

$$\phi^*\omega(v_1,...,v_k):=\omega(\phi_*v_1,...,\phi_*v_k)$$

where $\omega \in \Omega^k(T_pN^n)$ and $v_1,...,v_m \in T_pM$.

$\textbf{Hint}$: You don't have to use the definition given above but only a very useful property of it:

$$\rho^*(f \ dy) = (f \circ \rho) \ d(y \circ \rho)$$

$\textbf{Edit}$: $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ so we have $f = f(x,y)$. Here $\rho(a,b) = (b,a) \Rightarrow y \circ \rho = b$ and so $d(b) = 0$. Hence, you have $\rho(f \ dy) = ( f \circ \rho) \cdot 0 = 0$ i.e you just need $f$ s.t:

$$\alpha = - df = - f_x \ dx - f_y \ dy$$

Evaluating both sides by $\partial_x=\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial_y=\partial/\partial y$ you have: $\alpha =  (\alpha \circ \partial_x) \ dx + (\alpha \circ \partial_y) \ dy$. This comes from the fact that:

$$\alpha \circ \partial_x = \left(- f_x \ dx - f_y \ dy\right)(\partial_x) = -f_x \iff f_x = - \alpha \circ \partial_x = 0 \iff f = \int 0 \ dx = h(y)$$

$$f_y= - \alpha \circ \partial_y = - \left(\dfrac{\log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{\log(1-x)}{y}\right) \iff f = - \int \dfrac{\log(x)}{1-y} - \dfrac{\log(1-x)}{y} \ dy$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am having trouble seeing what $(f \circ \rho)$ represents, I'd understand what $(\rho \cir g)$ would be because $f$ is a 0-differential form but not the other way around. Could you give me an example (sorry for my lack of understanding)

Comment: Take $ f=x+y $ then the composition is $ a+b $.

Comment: Then what would be $y \circ \rho$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried to use the property you gave in your hint and I simply can't make sense out of it. Could you show me what $\rho(fdy)$ would be in my case? (fdy = $\alpha$)

Comment: Sorry I was away, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Thank You Very much. Also I looked you up on the internet, you're a big inspiration

Comment: I believe you made a typing mistake, second line after your edit I believe it's: $\rho^*(fdy) = (f \circ \rho).0$

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "$f_x$". I saw that $df =  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x)dx + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partal y} dy$ So is $f_x$ just another notation for $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta x}$?

Comment: Yes, it is just another notation for partial.